# deserialize api blueprint json ast using jackson

Tags: json, jackson, abstract-syntax-tree, apiblueprint, drafter

api blueprint reference : https://apiblueprint.org/
api blueprint AST reference : https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-ast

I'm using jackson to deserialise api blueprint ast (generated by Drafter) and I got stuck at polymorphic subtypes present in Element object of json AST. Basically it depends on element field and the content field changes accordingly in Element object.

Note : I tried with JsonSubTypes and JsonTypeInfo annotations, but no use..
Thanks!!

Comment: [Element object in json AST reference](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-ast#element-object)

Comment: API Blueprint is moving from AST to Refract. You can find more info at https://github.com/refractproject

Comment: @PavanKumarSunkara thanks for the update.. I executed the api blueprint examples and verified that the Element object in JSON AST which is generated by drafter is not following the AST spec when element enum is "category" (in Element Object), hope you got. I was also about to raise an issue in github drafter!!